# View and print address of variable in Arm Assembly

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B. I've done a simple program in ARM assembly that stores a constant value #10, into the address of a variable declared in the data section.

Now, I am trying to view the address of that variable. I used the GDB debugger to do so.

My question is:

1. Based on the screenshot, is this the address of my variable? 0X21024
2. If that's the address, Is there a way to view the full length of it?
3. Is there a way to output the address to the terminal using printf?

[image]

```
@; This is Data section
.data

.balign 4       
variable1: .word 1

.balign 4
return: .word 0

.balign 4
string: .asciz "%d\n"

.text
.balign 4 

.global main    
main:

    LDR R1, addr_of_return         
    STR LR, [R1]                         

    LDR R1, addr_of_var1    
    MOV R3, #10            
    STR R3, [R1]

    LDR R0, addr_of_string
    LDR R1, [R1]                        
    BL printf
    
    LDR LR, addr_of_return          
    LDR LR, [LR]                         
    BX LR
         

addr_of_var1 : .word variable1
addr_of_return : .word return
addr_of_string : .word string
```

Comment: Yes, `0X21024` is the address.  I'm not sure what you mean by "full length".  Do you want to print it with leading zeros like `0x00021024`?

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry, please ignore point 2. Is there a way to print 0X21024 to the screen using printf?

Comment: @lssaki Sure, use the `%p` formatting specifier and pass the address of the variable to `printf`.

Comment: @fuz Hi, I have another question. Is there a way to use two different format specifiers? For example: string: .asciz "%d\n %p"

Comment: @fuz Or do I need to create another variable: string_2: .asciz "%p" and call to BL print again?

Comment: @Issaki Sure, you can use as many specifiers as you like.  For each specifier pass the datum you want to print for it.  If you want to print the same datum with multiple formatting specifiers, pass it multiple times.  Read the manual for printf (`man 3 printf`) for details!

Comment: @fuz Hi, I've changed my variable to this: string: .asciz "%d %p\n" and included an extra line: LDR R1, R1. But now, I am receiving an error: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up

Comment: @lssaki What is `ldr r1, r1` supposed to mean?  For the assembler, this instruction tries to load register `r1` with the contents of a variable named `r1` which is nonsensical.